# Incorrect Syntax Near FOR in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert multiple rows of column into single row using comma `,` delimiter in SQL Server.

I tried this code, but I am getting parsing error:

```sql
SELECT ID + ', ' As 'Data()'
FROM Test_schema.Table_name 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

where `test_schema` is schema name and `Table_name` is table name with 2000 distinct IDs and 8 columns.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The statement you have given us doesn't generate that error.

Comment: Single quotes are used for literal strings, not for aliases. XML doesn't like parentheses so remove them (this caused your error): `ID + ', ' As [Data]` (If ID is not a string datatype you'll need to cast it first). This still won't give you the result you are looking for, I think. There are many extensive examples on how to do this (search for something like `GROUP_CONCAT in SQL SERVER`)

Comment: I tried the aliasing as you mentioned and also checked data type and it is string., but still same error

Comment: @Larnu do i need to change any settings? to work FOR XML Path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the SQL you have won't generate the error you state you get. If you try running the above you get the following error:

> Column name 'Data()' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '('(0x0028) is the first character at fault.

This is because XML nodes can't have parenthesis (`()`) in their name.

It sounds, like, however, that you shouldn't even be aliasing as you want a concatenated list of all your `ID`'s from your table. If so, then your query should actually look like this:

```sql
SELECT STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', ',ID) --I assume ID could be a non-string type
              FROM Test_schema.Table_name 
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');
```

If, however, you're on a more recent version of SQL Server, just us `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(ID,', ')
FROM Test_schema.Table_name;
```